# Using interpolated scope field names in form made with angularjs and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to produce a form using ng-repeat. The name of scope variable that I would like to have result of input to be located I am giving as one of parameters, so it has to be interpolated.

**Plunker for tweaking is located at  http://plnkr.co/edit/PPz2THeOOUZRazkuLeT6 .**

Here's the definition of form

```
$scope.formFields = [                       
 {
  id: "sample11",
  nextfree: 'rcv.UseNextFreeSampleId',
  ngmodel: 'rcv.SampleId',
  maxlen: 10,
  focus: false,
  useNextFree: true,
  useHint: true,
  text: {status: "status must be shown"}
}
];
```

where I specify that $scope.rcv.SampleId should contain the result.

HTML looks like:

```
<input class="input-small form-control" ng-required="!{{field.nextfree}}" type='text'    
    id='field.id' ng-model='{{field.ngmodel}}'
    ng-maxlength='field.maxlen'  ng-disabled='{{field.nextfree}}>
<span class="input-group-addon" ng-show='field.useNextFree'>
      <input type = "checkbox", ng-model='{{field.nextfree}}'  ng-value = "true" >
      <label>Use Option</label>
</span>
<span class="help-block small" ng-show='field.useHint'>{{field.text.status}}</span>
```

However when I check $scope.rcv, nothing is there from the input field and some other problems also persist. My quesions are

- How I can achieve the state when $scope.rcv.SampleId is filled from the input code shown above?
- Similarly, how I can achieve the situation when ng-required performs properly (field is requred if checkbox is not checked, otherwise it is disabled, but the scope variable is specified by name to be interpolated?
- why ng-maxlength has no effect?
- why {{field.text.status}} text displayed instead of contents of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular won't allow you to use interpolated values as ng-model.

You can achieve what you're looking for by altering your fields slightly `nextfree: 'UseNextFreeSampleId', ngmodel: 'SampleId'` and then referencing them as a property of $scope.rvc: `ng-model="rcv[field.ngmodel]"`

[See plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pAjnedZ1z2TGkiuOXlEg?p=preview)